# Pickle module that imports code with C bindings

Tags: python, cython, pickle

I have a class I want to pickle using this function:

```py
def _pickle(self):
    """Pickle model instance.
    """
    fpath = f'{directory}/model.pickle'
    with open(fpath, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(self, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

However, in my file I import a library, [PyPolyaGamma](https://github.com/slinderman/pypolyagamma). It's a Python wrapper for some C code that does fast sampling from the Polya-gamma distribution. When I try to pickle my class, I get this error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fit_model.py", line 262, in <module>
    model.fit(Y)
  File "/Users/gwg/projects/cdnlvm/kl_gplvmbase.py", line 97, in fit
    self._plot_and_print(t)
  File "/Users/gwg/projects/cdnlvm/kl_nbgplvm.py", line 456, in _plot_and_print
    self._pickle()
  File "/Users/gwg/projects/cdnlvm/kl_gplvmbase.py", line 352, in _pickle
    pickle.dump(self_, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "stringsource", line 2, in pypolyagamma.pypolyagamma.PyPolyaGamma.__reduce_cython__
TypeError: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__
```

My understanding is that Python does not know how to serialize the PyPolyaGamma code, probably because of the dependency on C. What is the correct way to handle this?

---

Here is a minimal and complete example, if you're willing to install PyPolyaGamma:

```py
# pickle_test.py

import pickle
from   pypolyagamma import PyPolyaGamma

class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pg = PyPolyaGamma()

model = Model()
with open('test.pickle', 'wb+') as f:
    pickle.dump(model, f)
```

This will output:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pickle_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    pickle.dump(model, f)
  File "stringsource", line 2, in pypolyagamma.pypolyagamma.PyPolyaGamma.__reduce_cython__
TypeError: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like that pypolyagamma library you use doesn't currently support pickling/unpickling those objects, so in a word: you can't pickle them without modifying the library.

Furthermore, since it wraps a C++ class, the pickler/unpickler isn't trivial; it'd need to know what state from [that wrapped class](https://github.com/slinderman/pypolyagamma/blob/b5883e661123862ca07d29ab14369fae85bdbc27/pypolyagamma/cpp/PolyaGammaHybrid.h#L15-L27) is necessary for the object to be in the same state after unpickling.

Comment: I thought this might be the case. I'm willing to put in the effort to modify the library (and possibly PR it) since it is important to me—eventually, I need this for parallelization. Do you know the basic outline of how to do this? The only two attributes that are necessary to unpickle are two integers, `seed` and `trunc`. Everything else is stateless. Happy to ask this as a separate question if you think that's warranted.

Comment: If those are the only things that are actually necessary, it'd be certainly easier to just wrap the C++ class in a Python class of your own that does support the `__reduce__`/`__setstate__` protocol (and rebuild the C++ object from those integers within `__setstate__`)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to a wrapper and if you don't mind using a functional interface, then I would recommend using [polyagamma](https://github.com/zoj613/polya-gamma) instead. This resolves issues with pickling. Its a python package for Polya-Gamma variable sampling written in C. It is flexible and allows using different sampling methods and has an API that resembles Numpy's. You can install the latest version via `pip install -U polyagamma`.